# Stringsplit for special characters, but not if they appear one after another?

Tags: java, regex

I'm splitting a string on parenthesis like this:

```
string.split("\\(\\)");
```

Now the following should be split into 5 words:

```
This (is ((()(my test text)
```

What do I have to change so that if any of the split characters follows another one, then there should not be a split.

Expected result would be:

```
This
is
my test text
```

Comment: Why would a split on parenthesis split the string between `This` and `is`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the regex select more than only two adjacent parenthesis:

```
[()]+
```

```
string.split("[()]+"); // or "(?:\\(|\\))+"
```

Comment: Great! How could I also exclude whitespaces in between more tan one parenthesis, eg `(   )   (` should also not produce a split token?

Comment: Add them to the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that is repeated: `[()\s)]+` (notice that then there would be a split on the whitespace between `test` and `text` as well)

Comment: @membersound try `([()] *)+`

Comment: If you don't want that, it would need to become a little less ambiguous: `\s*[()][()\s]*` (at least one parenthesis, optionally preceded by whitespaces and followed by an arbitrary number of whitespaces or parenthesis